# Find a number N so that the error/remainder is less than 0.02

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am a calculus student who tries to learn about Taylor polynomials and how to find the remainder/error margins.

I am starting to get my head around some of the basics, but unfortunately, I got stuck on this problem. Therefore I would massively appreciate it if someone could provide me with a solution to this problem and help me in my learning:

**Given the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$**

1. Find the Taylor approximation for the n-th order in the point $a=1$ and find an expression for the remainder $R_nf(x)$.
2. Find a natural number $N$ so that for all n $\geq$ N and for all x $\in[1, 1.25]$ the error in $T_nf(x)$ is less than 0.02

**In the first question I have gotten this far (and it is hopefully correct)**
$T_nf(x)=\sum_{n}^{k=0}\frac{f^k(1)}{k!}(x-1)^k=1-2(x-1)+3(x-1)^2+..+\frac{f^{(k+1)}\cdot(c)}{(k+1)!}$

where $\frac{f^{(k+1)}\cdot(c)}{(k+1)!}=R_n(x)$

I think I have found an acceptable expression for the remainder for the n-th order.

**However, I am more unsure of how to go about the second part of the problem - where the task is to find an error margin smaller than 0.02**

I the textbook I'm using there are no good examples to look at, that are similar.

**My questions are:**

1. Is my expression for finding the remainder $\frac{f^{(k+1)}\cdot(c)}{(k+1)!}=R_n(x)$ correct?
2. How do you find the number c? (since it is the n-th order)
3. Is there anyone who can show me how to find the number N where the error margin is smaller than 0.02?

All help is welcomed and appreciated.

**NB!:** I suspect that the information from a previous subtask might be relevant: (previously I have shown that $f^{k}(x)=\frac{(-1)^k(k+1)!}{x^{k+2}}$ for all $k\geq0$ by induction)

Comment: Can you please clean up the math? There are some places that make me suspect that you don't understand what the notation means.

Comment: @Dmitry: As I tried to explain in the introduction to my question; this is new to me - so there might be some notation I am not 100% comfortable with. However, I cleaned it up as much as I could to the best of my current abilities. Hopefully, it is a bit easier to understand my question now.

Comment: Can you spot what's wrong with $\frac{f^{(k+1)}\cdot(c)}{(k+1)!}$ and $f^{k}(x)=\frac{(-1)^k(k+1)!}{k^{k+2}}$?

Comment: In practice you'd use the actual Taylor formula as little as possible. In this case the binomial theorem can produce the series: $\frac{1}{x^2} = 1-2(x-1)+3(x-1)^2-4(x-1)^3 \dots$.

Comment: @Dmitry: In the first expression i suspect I should have written $\frac{f^{(k+1)}\cdot(c)}{(k+1)!}\cdot(x-1)^{n+1}$ instead. With the second expression, I'm not sure
what you mean.  Can you help me out?

Comment: It seems you don’t understand what kind of object $f^{(k)}$ is, so I suggest you to carefully study derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

$c$ is in the interval $[1,1.25]$.  You can only find it if you solve the problem exactly, which you are not expected to do.  You are expected to replace $c$ with the value that maximizes the error, which here is $1$.  Once you do that, you just compute the error term at each order until it is below $0.02$

Comment: I think $1$ maximizes the error here.

Comment: @B.Goddard:  you are right.  Fixed.  Thanks.  I confused the point where the approximation is worst with the $c$ that makes the error bound worst.

Comment: @B. Goddard - I'm pretty sure the error is *minimized* at 1. Usually (not always so it's not a theorem) the further you are from $a$ the larger the error is. In this case it's not too hard to see that the error term is monotone, so the maximum is at an endpoint. The error at 1 is 0 so the maximum occurs at 1.25.

Comment: @RDBury In the error term, $x$ is in the denominator.  The smaller the denominator, the larger the fraction.  The smallest value of $x$ is $1$, so $c=1$ bounds the error term.

Comment: @B. Goddard - You're right, I was confusing the error bound in the theorem with the error. The error has a factor of $(x-1)^{k+1}$ so *it* will be minimized at $x=1$